# Alien dwarves that can conduct electricity

Tags: story-identification, tv

In a sci-fi series from the late 1970s to mid 1980s I recall an episode in which two alien dwarves could allow high current electricity to pass through their body without harm. There may have been more than two of these aliens though I only recall seeing the two.

Apparently they were friendly aliens and agreeable to helping the hero of the show who had asked them to act as jumpers for open circuits. The two dwarf aliens happily assisted.

The rest of the story I can't recall. It was likely from one of the popular series of that time such as Battlestar Galactica, Buck Rogers or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0420373/) could be a match, it is an episode from Buck Rodgers in the 25th century entitled "shgorathx." But the excerpt I found doesn't mention the dwarves being shock proof. Nor could they exactly be considered helpful, as they ended up almost blowing up Buck's ship do to their incompetence.

> The Searcher finds a derelict Zardonian bomb disposal ship crewed by seven mischievous little men. Buck offers to help them finish their disposal mission, but the curious dwarves begin to wreak havoc aboard the Searcher and severely damage Crichton's positronic brain. With the ship out of control and heading toward a star, Twiki offers his own electronic brain to repair Crichton so he can initiate repairs to the ship. Once the dwarves realize the trouble they have caused, they offer to repair Crichton's brain with their telekinetic mental powers.

Comment: That seems close, but I don't recall any of the havoc part. The dwarves or midgets were sedate and mostly sedentary. They didn't seem to part of a larger crew and they likely had less of a role in the story than the ones in the story you suggested. What they did seem to be was part of a collection of unusual characters with unusual capacities that served lesser roles to add interest to the story. I'll try to find the episode you mention and watch it but it seems to be available only by payment.

Comment: Are you sure it was a TV show. The description you give sounds a lot like the Kelvin in Battle Beyond the Stars. You can watch it on youtube. The Kelvin have a scene starting at 1 hour 16 minutes which might be what you remember. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFA6FnOqfwI this film used a lot of sound effects familiar from Battlestar Galactica and the SFX shots where reused in other films.

Comment: dominic- I skimmed through the movie you mentioned and believe I had seen it in the 80s. While its typical of space movies of that time and has many similarities to the scene I recall, the tone of the movie is different from the sitcom feel of the show in question.

Comment: I found some reviews of this episode and its mentioned in them that the midgets can conduct electricity.